# Eclipse problems with JNI and android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a problem regarding the android.mk in Eclipse. Here is the code:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := hellocpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libhellocpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
```

the problem lies in the last line of the code. The error also says "Android NDK: aborting. . Stop" Any ideas on how I can solve this? I'm new to coding so if you could put it in layman's terms? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have you defined `COCOS2DX` path variable?

Comment: yup, I defined the path for cocos2dx

Comment: Please, explain the whole process of compilation you performed. It may be important as cocos2dx-app needs tuning project properties. Have you managed compiling a sample game project from cocos2dx samples directory?

Comment: these are the tools that I used, MinGW, cocos2dx, eclipse kepler, android ndk r9...

I built the package using MinGW, then imported it to eclipse kepler. Then I saw the error in JNI with and android.mk.

Am I doing something wrong, maybe skipped a step? Thanks!

Comment: try using http://www.cygwin.com/ instead of MinGW as recommended here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#reqs

Comment: but when I use cygwin, it looks for the GNUMAKE 3.81 file. So do I need to replace MinGW with that? Thank you Maxim!

Comment: I think you should indicate that the "GNUMAKE" package is needed on cygwin setup. And I don't know if MinGW should work, as I use only cygwin to compile my cocos2dx-projects.

Comment: When I use cygwin, it recognizes MinGW but prefers GNUMAKE. Is that normal? Okay, I will try that. I'll comment again if it works or not. Thanks again!